# Turtlebot not appearing on RViz during mapping

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, turtlebot-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM) to build a map with the turtlebot. The thing is that I can not see anything on the rviz. If I look at the topics on the left column I see that it has two problems: Pose Array and Path. Both have the same problem: No message received.
When I have a look at the diagnostics on turtlebot dashboard I get this message:

name: /slam_gmapping
msg: Transform from base_link to odom failed

file: /tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-slam-gmapping-1.2.3/debian/ros-diamondback-slam-gmapping/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/slam_gmapping/gmapping/src/slam_gmapping.cpp
function: laserCallback
line: 496
topics[]
topics[0]: /rosout
topics[1]: /tf
topics[2]: /slam_gmapping/entropy
topics[3]: /map
topics[4]: /map_metadata

My turtlebot doesn't have a gyro. Can this be the problem?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11824/turtlebot-not-appearing-on-rviz-during-mapping/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2011-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From my experience Gmapping without the gyro will give the same results as you mentioned. Turtlebot doesn't move around the map. I believe this is due to the fact it obviously needs the gyro data to localize it self properly . I assume you could use RXGraph to find where the missing data link in gmapping is and possibly write your own code to create data to determine your robots location but, if I were you I would just invest in the recommended gyro.

---

Originally posted by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) with karma: 458 on 2011-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

checkout http://www.ros.org/wiki/roomba_500_series. You will find a roomba560_node.cpp. For mapping you have to add a joint state publisher, just like turtlebot_node does.

---

Originally posted by [MichiReip](https://answers.ros.org/users/1360/michireip/) with karma: 11 on 2011-11-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1